# Variance of sum of random variables - Confused

Tags: statistics, variance

Suppose $X_i$ 's are i.i.d and by sum of random variables, then $Var(X_1 + X_2) = Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)$.

However, since $X_i$ are i.i.d, then $X_1 + X_2 = 2 X_1$, then $Var(X_1 + X_2) = Var(2X_1) = 4 Var(X_1)$.

Which part of my logic went wrong here ?

Comment: How do you justify $X_1+X_2=2X_1$ ???

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, $X_1+X_2$ cannot be written a $2X_1$ or $2X_2$.Only, $Var(X_1+X_2)=Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)$. Because, covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ will be zero

Comment: I hate how the first person who ever rolled a die rolled a six, and now every die in the world lands on six every time. It's so boring playing craps when you get nothing but boxcars.

Comment: You seem to use '$X_2=X_1$'. But that '$=$' is not the usual equality; it is equality *in distribution*.

Answer (score 0):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed random variables but this does not mean realisations of those random variables will result in identical numbers.

To make this more concrete, consider e.g.
$$
X_1 \sim N(0,1)
$$
$$
X_2 \sim N(0,1)
$$
These are i.i.d. but it doesn't mean that $X_1+X_2 \sim 2\,N(0,1)$ as you suggest.